# Generate a hyperlink to a filter for each day of the year

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am tying to create a script that will generate a hyperlink for each day of the calendar year, then automatically filter the data on another sheet based on the date.

For example, on 08/02/23 the hyperlink will open the "Data" sheet and filter the data so only the data with 08/02/23 in column "C" will be visible.
The hyperlinks will be placed on a sheet called 'linked'. This is what I have at the moment, but cannot get it to work:

```
function createLinks() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var linksSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Links");
  
  if (!dataSheet) {
    ss.insertSheet("Data");
    dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  }
  if (!linksSheet) {
    ss.insertSheet("Links");
    linksSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Links");
  }
  
  var startDate = new Date(2023, 0, 1);
  var endDate = new Date(2023, 11, 31);
  
  var currentDate = startDate;
  var row = 1;
  
  while (currentDate <= endDate) {
    var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(currentDate, "GMT", "dd/MM/yy");
    var link = "=HYPERLINK(\"#gid=" + dataSheet.getSheetId() + "&range=" + dateString + "\", \"" + dateString + "\")";
    
    linksSheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(link);
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    row++;
  }
}
```

Would it also be possible to add in any other conditions - e.g. hyperlink to the "data" sheet that show data from said date & but only if column "A" contains "xyz".

Will appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And also, I cannot understand `but cannot get it to work:`. So, also can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike, thank you for the reply. - I want to create a script that generates a hyperlink to the sheet "data". The script should create a link for each calendar day of 2023. Once the link is clicked it takes you to the "data" sheet & automatically sets a filter to the dates in column 'C' based on the date from the hyperlink. For example, if the hyperlink is 01/01/23, once clicked it takes you to the "data" sheet then applies a filter to column C to show only data on 01/01/23

Comment: @Tanaike I want to create a hyperlink for each day of 2023 that goes to the sheet "data" and automatically sets a filter based on the date of the hyperlink. - I don't know how else to explain it